# RestTemplate Interceptor

Tags: java, spring, interceptor, resttemplate

I'm currently trying to incorporate a `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` but it's not getting registered and comparing it to other answers is tough because everyone is using something different. And I'm aware WebMvcConfigureAdapter is deprecated, some versioning is beyond my control for the scope of the project,  see usage specs below.

Can someone please provide some guidance on incorporating interceptors with a RestTemplate (that's not ClientHttpRequestInterceptor).

Main:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRetry
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

   ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

  }


  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder) {

    return applicationBuilder.sources(Application.class);

  }

  @Bean
  private RestTemplate restTemplate(){
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("redacted", 8080));

    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory simpleClientHttpRequestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    simpleClientHttpRequestFactory.setProxy(proxy);
    simpleClientHttpRequestFactory.setOutputStreaming(false);

    RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
    template.setErrorHandler(new MyResponseErrorHandler());

    return template;
  }
}
```

Interceptor  : com.example.foo.config.request.interceptor

```java
@Component
public class MyInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

  @Override
  public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("INTERCEPTED");
    return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
  }
}
```

InterceptorConfig : com.example.foo.config.request.interceptor

```java
@Configuration
public class InterceptorConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  {

  @Bean
  MyInterceptor myInterceptor() {
    return new MyInterceptor();
  }

  @Override
  public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    super.addInterceptors(registry);
    System.out.println("Adding interceptor");
    registry.addInterceptor(myInterceptor());
  }

}
```

"Adding interceptor" does get logged so I know the configs are being scanned. I just can't get any interceptor logic to log.

Using:

- Spring Boot v1.5.15
- Spring Version: 4.3.18.RELEASE

Comment: I think the problem is related to you initiating the `RestTemplate`. Please use it with autowired `@Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;`. Even the interceptor should be `Autowired`. I would suggest see this project as an example https://github.com/Asatnin/SpringMicroservices/blob/f4899546e8c3c37a5d4008f7f47562b2a87892eb/CourseService/src/main/java/com/zavalin/config/WebMvcConfig.java

Comment: Thanks @TarunLalwani I tried AutoWiring before asking the question and it didn't matter, I AutoWire the Rest Template in my Service as well. You're example looks very similar to my set up but your interceptor uses the rest exchange method so maybe that is the key. I will try and update you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RestTemplate expects [ClientHttpRequestInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/support/InterceptingHttpAccessor.html)

> ```
> setInterceptors(List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors)
> ```
>
> Set the request interceptors that this accessor should use.

You can use [Servlet Filter](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) to "intercept" requests/response,

> ```
> @Override
> public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
>         throws IOException, ServletException {
>     HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
>     HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
> ```
>
> implement this with a servlet filter. No Spring involved here at all

But you will have to change RestTemplate to using other framework as [jersey](https://dev.to/shriharshmishra/comparing-springs-resttemplate-and-jerseys-client-apis-350)

> Jersey gives a very handy implementation of such as filter called LoggingFilter which can help in logging all kinds of incoming and outgoing traffic.

Comment: Thanks. I will try a filter and keep you updated! This could be an obvious oversight! And thanks for being concise and straight to the point. Sometimes it's not about *why* the OP wants to do it, it's just about *how* to get it done

Comment: Servlet filters can only intercept the requests that come INTO the application. I guess what the OP wants is to intercept requests that go OUT of an app via restTemplate. Am I correct @soulshined?

Comment: @MadhuBhat for outgoing requests    http://www.corej2eepatterns.com/Patterns/InterceptingFilter.htm

Comment: @user7294900 that only tells about intercepting request that come into the controller right? Or am I missing something? Would it intercept requests that go out of the app via resttemplate or any other http client?

Comment: @MadhuBhat I update my answer with link *you will have to change RestTemplate to using other framework as jersey*

Comment: I’m trying to intercept requests and responses in a more flexible way than ClientHttpRequestInterceptor affords @MadhuBhat I will test this tonight after I get off work

Comment: @soulshined but do you want to intercept requests coming into your app or going out of your app?

Comment: Seems to be filter is the way to go for 'intercepting' requests/responses in conjunction with `RestTemplate` while not using `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

`HandlerInterceptorAdapter` is an implementation that applies to `@Controller` or `@RestController`. Not an implementation for `RestTemplete`.

To apply it to `RestTemplete`, you need to use `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`.

ex.

```java
@Component
public class CustomInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {
    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        // ... 
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuation
public class RestTempleteConfig {

    // ...
    @Autowired
    private CustomInterceptor customInterceptor;

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(){
        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
        List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<>();
        template.add(customInterceptor);
        return template;
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP explicitly mentions this is not a desired solution. And of course I'm using a mixture of Services and RestControllers. Thanks for the feedback though!

Answer (score 0):

As @WonChulHeo noted you can't use `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` with `RestTemplate`. Only `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`. It's not clear why do you need exactly `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` - we can only see that you are trying to log the fact of the request interception. And `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` is absolutely able to do the same and even more - check my working example bellow.

P.S. There is an error in your code - you can't use `private` access for `@Bean` methods - check your `private RestTemplate restTemplate() {` please...

```java
@Slf4j
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
                .bannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF)
                .run(args);
    }

    @GetMapping("/users/{id}")
    public User get(@PathVariable int id) {
        log.info("[i] Controller: received request GET /users/{}", id);
        return new User(id, "John Smith");
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder templateBuilder) {
        ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory());
        return templateBuilder
                .interceptors((request, bytes, execution) -> {
                    URI uri = request.getURI();
                    HttpMethod method = request.getMethod();

                    log.info("[i] Interceptor: requested {} {}", method, uri);
                    log.info("[i] Interceptor: request headers {}", request.getHeaders());

                    ClientHttpRequest delegate = requestFactory.createRequest(uri, method);
                    request.getHeaders().forEach((header, values) -> delegate.getHeaders().put(header, values));

                    ClientHttpResponse response = delegate.execute();
                    log.info("[i] Interceptor: response status: {}", response.getStatusCode().name());
                    log.info("[i] Interceptor: response headers: {}", response.getHeaders());
                    String body = StreamUtils.copyToString(response.getBody(), Charset.defaultCharset());
                    log.info("[i] Interceptor: response body: '{}'", body);

                    return response;
                })
                .rootUri("http://localhost:8080")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner run(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        return args -> {
            ResponseEntity<User> response = restTemplate.getForEntity("/users/{id}", User.class, 1);
            if (response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
                log.info("[i] User: {}", response.getBody());
            } else {
                log.error("[!] Error: {}", response.getStatusCode());
            }
        };
    }
}
```

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {
    private int id;
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. As noted, I'm not trying to use ClientHttpRequestInterceptor, and the reasons why are a unique edge case that wouldn't be helpful to future readers and could potentially solicit answers that aren't applicable.

Answer (score 0):

The `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` is for the server side (i.e. RestController) to intercept some important events when server processes a HTTP request , it is nothing to do with what HTTP client (e.g `RestTemplate`) is used.

If you want to use `RestTemplate` as a HTTP client and want to intercept the request just before it sent out and the response just after it received , you must use `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`.

> I’m trying to intercept requests and responses in a more flexible way
>   than ClientHttpRequestInterceptor.

From your comment above , what is your actual use-cases that it cannot handle ? I think `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` is already quite flexible enough to implement any complex logic to intercept request and response. As your question does not provide any information about how you need to intercept , I can only give a general example to show what the `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` can offer .

To configure the RestTemplate to use an interceptor :

```
RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();
List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors= new ArrayList<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor>();
inteceptors.add(new MyClientHttpRequestInterceptor());
```

And the ClientHttpRequestInterceptor looks like:

```
public class MyClientHttpRequestInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor{

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution)
            throws IOException {

        //The HTTP request and its body are intercepted here which you can log them or modify them. e.g.
        System.out.println("Log the HTTP request header: " + request.getHeaders());

        //Modify the HTTP request header....
        request.getHeaders().add("foo", "fooValue");

        //Throw exception if you do not want to send the HTTP request

        //If it is at the end of the interceptor chain , call execution.execute() to confirm sending the HTTP request will return the response in ClientHttpResponse
        //Otherwise, it will pass the request to the next interceptor in the chain to process
        ClientHttpResponse response= execution.execute(request, body);

        //The HTTP response is intercepted here which you can log them or modify them.e.g.
        System.out.println("Log the HTTP response header: " + response.getHeaders());

        //Modify the HTTP response header
        response.getHeaders().add("bar", "barValue");

        return response;
    }
}
```

Please note that you can also configure a chain of `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` which allows to split some complex request and response intercept logic into many smalls and reusable `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`. It is designed with the [Chain of responsibility](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) design pattern which its API experience is very similar to what `Filter#doFilter()` in `Servlet`.

Comment: im completely with you. perhaps he can/could/should create a class that implements both interfaces an/or inherit from an abstract super-class that holds similarities?

Comment: The things that I don't quite understand is that if OP just want to intercept the request / response when using a HTTP client ,  how does it matter and why need to care how the server intercept the request / response ?

Comment: i have read all answers and comments and i also dont really understand. on one hand hes afraid of deprecation, on the other he rather uses `RestTemplate`than `WebClient`. the api dictates its requirements and we have to fit these requirement. my suggestion was/is my best guess, what he might want to achieve.

Comment: I'm not afraid of deprecation, as I mentioned, versioning is beyond my control and `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` does not work for my needs, lets even just say for arbitrary reasons for the sake of argument. Why it doesn't is irrelevant and would absolutely be against SO etiquette by asking a question 'too broad' or 'not sure what you're asking'. I've narrowed the ask down to something very simple, intercept requests/responses with RestTemplate that's not ClientHttpRequestInterceptor. At the end of the day it doesn't matter why, the ask is **how**.

Comment: @soulshined , understand.  So how do your final solution become ? I re-read the accept answer and still cannot find any information about how to do it with `RestTemplate` without using `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` . Do I miss something here ? Can you share your final solution such that community here can learn a way to intercept which may be  better than the existing `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` way  provided by `RestTemplate`?  ‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️ Thanks.