# How to consume a JWT secured microservice from another microservice Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt, microservices

My application has several microservices including: Auth, Game and Group.
When I press a button on front end (Play) I'm calling Group rest api method, let's say foo().
In order to implement foo() inside Group I need to GET call Game rest api, but it's secured.

When I login in on React app I get the JWT token from /login (Auth) and store it in localstorage. Then I successfully use it to call foo() from Group but in foo() implementation I also need to use the jwt token in order to be able to get information from Game.

```
@Configuration
//+component scans...
public class GroupConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public WebClient.Builder buildWebClientBuilder() {

        return WebClient.builder();
    }
}


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/groups")
public class Controller {

    private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Autowired
    private WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;

private int getMinimumNumberOfPlayers(int gameId) {

        try {
            return webClientBuilder.build()
                    .get()
                    .uri("http://game-service/games/minimumNumberOfPlayers/2")
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(Integer.class)
                    .block();
        } catch (NullPointerException|WebClientResponseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }
    }

...

// foo() frontend calls foo(). foo it's using getMinimumNumberOfPlayers
```

getMinimumNumberOfPlayers() is used in foo() method from Group. It's supposed to retrieve the minimum number of players of a game by id, but the game microservice is jwt secured and i get an unauthorized error.

So my question is how can i make Group microservice be able to call Game microservice.

Thanks.

Edit: [RestTemplate Interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57516825/resttemplate-interceptor)
This is how I solved it.

Comment: That's normally not how you implement system-to-system communication. Oauth for example has different flows for user-to-system and system-to-system communcation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if I have some security issues, I will answer this question :

What you could do is :

1. add an interceptor for incoming calls on your Group service that will store the JWT in the `request context`.
2. add an interceptor for outgoing calls to your Game service that will get the JWT in the `request context` and add it to the request headers.

What is important here is the `request context`.