How to get HttpRequest in @ExceptionHandler with RestClientException?
I am developing an internal shared library in my company that needs to intercept all exceptions and format them into a single DTO (a bit simplified).
{
    "serviceName": "my-service-name",
    "errorCode": "ExternalRequestException",
    "externalServiceUrl": "http://external-service.com:8080/api/method-name?param=1"
    "externalErrorCode": "InvalidArgumentException",
    "externalErrorMessage": "Invalid argument param ...."
    "internalErrors": [],
}

I have no problem handling WebClientRequestException or WebClientResponseException in @ExceptionHandler because they contain a requestUrl or a whole HttpRequest to get the target url of the request.
So, I can add org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.Client.ClientResponse#createException to webClient as follows
var response = webClient
            .get()
            .uri(“http://external-service.com:8080/api/method-name?param=1”)
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatusCode::isError, ClientResponse::createException)
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .block();

and I will be 100% sure that the WebClientRequestException or WebClientResponseException thrown by this call will contain the request url (http://external-service.com:8080/api/method-name?param=1 in this example).
So, the main question is how to get the request information while restClient throws the exception? Maybe I need to develop some restClientInterceptor or something similar to enrich the standard exceptions with request specific information.
updates:

A little investigation from me: it seems that by default exceptions are created in org.springframework.web.client.StatusHandler#defaultHandler and HttpRequest is available in the context of this handler, but it is not used at all. This confuses me because I think the request information can be useful, especially for 4xx exceptions.
I have created a issue in a spring-framework project. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/33814


And so, for many reasons, I decided to write my own implementation rest-client-call-exception. I posted it on github and published it on maven-central. Everybody welcome to use, discuss and contribute.

If you add HttpServletRequest to the handler function parameter, spring can automatically inject information and use it.
    @ExceptionHandler(RestClientException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleRestClientException(RestClientException ignoredE, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String uri = request.getRequestURI();
        
        log.info("Request URI {}", uri);
        //.. add another request info log

        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }


I'm not 100% sure, but ServletRequest is not about the restClient's destination for the call, it's about my api (@RestController) uri. My question is not about it, my question is about HttpRequest.

If so, I think you can handle it by inheriting the intercept function of ClientHttpRequestInterceptor.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57518027/23297027

Don’t go with @ExceptionHandler. It would become problematic for other custom expectations in future.
For your problem I would create
Create a Custom Exception:
public class CustomRestClientException extends RestClientException {
private final String requestUrl;

public CustomRestClientException(String message, Throwable cause, String requestUrl) {
    super(message, cause);
    this.requestUrl = requestUrl;
}

public String getRequestUrl() {
    return requestUrl;
} }

Add an Interceptor:
public class RestClientInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {
@Override
public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
    try {
        return execution.execute(request, body);
    } catch (RestClientException e) {
        throw new CustomRestClientException("External Reqyest Exception", e, request.getURI().toString());
    }
}}

Configure Your RestTemplate:
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new RestClientInterceptor());


So, you say to not use @ExceptionHandler but is there another way to globaly catch exceptions ? For example how i should "wrap" the CustomRestClientException that you mention, into a ResponseEntity<MyDtoForErrorResponse>

Yes you are correct .
